# HttpClient 4.2.5 workings with cookies

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

i just started to work with the HttpClient and i use it to login on my website. The problem is that i can't get cookies and so i can't stay logged in.

Here is my code, probably not very good... 
Can someone tell me how to handle cookies with this library? Or maybe it exists a documentation or tutorial where i can learn more about? (i already checked online documentation, wasn't very helpuf).

```
public MyHttpClient() {     
    this.client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    this.client.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY, CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);
}       

/**
 * Retourne le contenu d'une requête POST
 * @param url L'url de la requêtes
 * @return Le contenu de la réponse à a reque^te
 */
public String sendRequest(String[] args){     
    String requestResponse = "";
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(MyHttpClient.AJAX_API_URL);
    try {            
        //Test avec httpClient
        HttpResponse response;
        HttpEntity entity;

        //Déclaration de la liste des valeurs
        List<BasicNameValuePair> listKeys = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i += 2){
            listKeys.add(new BasicNameValuePair(args[i],args[i+1]));
        }

        //On ajoute les clefs à la requete
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(listKeys,Consts.UTF_8));

        response = client.execute(post);            
        entity = response.getEntity();

        //Récupération des cookies
        for(Cookie cookie : client.getCookieStore().getCookies()){
            this.listCookies.add(cookie);                
            Logger.getLogger(MyHttpClient.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, "Cookie "+cookie.getName());
        }

        requestResponse = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MyHttpClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        post.releaseConnection();
    }

    return requestResponse;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by how to handle cookie ?

Comment: In my code, i don't receive any cookies, so my session is always reset. How can i use cookies with HttpClient to be able to retrieve and send the cookies with my request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try setting your own `cookieStore` like this:

```
private HttpClient client;
private CookieStore cookieStore;
private HttpContext httpContext;
```

And then in initialization:

```
            cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
            httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            httpContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
```

In your `sendRequest` method:

```
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post, httpContext);
```

You can checkout the full code in my [javautils](https://bitbucket.org/pdrzewin/java-utils) repo [here](https://bitbucket.org/pdrzewin/java-utils/src/d51cd42d224b463f7fa9f767831e301a91ceca06/src/main/java/pdrzewin/utils/http/PlainHttpClient.java?at=default)

Comment: I tried, but i still don't get any cookies. When i loop through the cookieStore.getCookies() and display their name or value in the console, there is nothing.

Comment: @OlivierCosquer did you try connecting to some other site? Maybe the problem lies somewhere else - not directly in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I tried to connect to an other website, then i received cookies (the one i expected: PHPSESSID) so i checked my php code and Tadaaaaa there is no session_start() so that's why the request didn't received any cookies.

Comment: shouldn't the server send me others cookies?